# How to interpret the log output of docplex optimisation library

Tags: optimization, cplex, docplex, docplexcloud

I am having a problem interpreting this log that I get after trying to maximise an objective function using docplex:

```
        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

      0     0        6.3105     0                     10.2106       26         
      0     0        5.9960     8                     Cone: 5       34         
      0     0        5.8464     5                     Cone: 8       47         
      0     0        5.8030    11                    Cone: 10       54         
      0     0        5.7670    12                    Cone: 13       64         
      0     0        5.7441    13                    Cone: 16       72         
      0     0        5.7044     9                    Cone: 19       81         
      0     0        5.6844    14                      5.6844      559         
*     0+    0                            4.5362        5.6844            25.31%
      0     0        5.5546    15        4.5362     Cuts: 322     1014   22.45%
      0     0        5.4738    15        4.5362      Cuts: 38     1108   20.67%
*     0+    0                            4.6021        5.4738            18.94%
      0     0        5.4296    16        4.6021     Cuts: 100     1155   17.98%
      0     0        5.3779    19        4.6021      Cuts: 34     1204   16.86%
      0     0        5.3462    17        4.6021      Cuts: 80     1252   16.17%
      0     0        5.3396    19        4.6021      Cuts: 42     1276   16.03%
      0     0        5.3364    24        4.6021      Cuts: 57     1325   15.96%
      0     0        5.3269    17        4.6021      Cuts: 66     1353   15.75%
      0     0        5.3188    20        4.6021      Cuts: 42     1369   15.57%
      0     0        5.2975    21        4.6021      Cuts: 62     1387   15.11%
      0     0        5.2838    24        4.6021      Cuts: 72     1427   14.81%
      0     0        5.2796    21        4.6021      Cuts: 70     1457   14.72%
      0     0        5.2762    24        4.6021      Cuts: 73     1471   14.65%
      0     0        5.2655    24        4.6021      Cuts: 18     1479   14.42%
*     0+    0                            4.6061        5.2655            14.32%
*     0+    0                            4.6613        5.2655            12.96%
      0     0        5.2554    26        4.6613      Cuts: 40     1492   12.75%
      0     0        5.2425    27        4.6613      Cuts: 11     1511   12.47%
      0     0        5.2360    23        4.6613       Cuts: 3     1518   12.33%
      0     0        5.2296    19        4.6613       Cuts: 7     1521   12.19%
      0     0        5.2213    18        4.6613       Cuts: 8     1543   12.01%
      0     0        5.2163    24        4.6613      Cuts: 15     1552   11.91%
      0     0        5.2106    21        4.6613       Cuts: 4     1558   11.78%
      0     0        5.2106    21        4.6613       Cuts: 3     1559   11.78%
*     0+    0                            4.6706        5.2106            11.56%
      0     2        5.2106    21        4.6706        5.2106     1559   11.56%
Elapsed time = 9.12 sec. (7822.43 ticks, tree = 0.01 MB, solutions = 5)
     51    29        4.9031     3        4.6706        5.1575     1828   10.42%
    260   147        4.9207     1        4.6706        5.1575     2699   10.42%
    498   242    infeasible              4.6706        5.0909     3364    9.00%
    712   346        4.7470     6        4.6706        5.0591     4400    8.32%
    991   497        4.7338     6        4.6706        5.0480     5704    8.08%
   1358   566        4.8085    11        4.6706        5.0005     7569    7.06%
   1708   708        4.7638    14        4.6706        4.9579     9781    6.15%
   1985   817        cutoff              4.6706        4.9265    11661    5.48%
   2399   843    infeasible              4.6706        4.9058    15567    5.04%
   3619   887        4.7066     4        4.6706        4.7875    23685    2.50%
Elapsed time = 17.75 sec. (10933.85 ticks, tree = 3.05 MB, solutions = 5)
   4623   500        4.6863    13        4.6706        4.7274    35862    1.22%
```

What I don't understand is the following:

1. What is the difference between the third (Objective) and fifth column (Best integer )
2. How come that the third column (Objective) has higher values than the actual solution of the problem given by CPLEX which is (4.6706)
3. Does the values in the third column take into consideration the constraints given to the optimization problem?

This [webpage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/para/52_node_log.html) didn't help me to understand neither, the explanation of **Best Integer** is really confusing.

Thank you in advance for your feedback.
Regards.

Comment: Simply explained: The values in the 'Best Integer' column are the objective function values for those solutions that actually satisfy all the constraints, i.e. those are true valid solutions. The values in the 'Objective' column: the problem is 'relaxed' in that some variables that should take integer values may not have integer values. The 'Objective' values will move around a lot while CPLEX hunts for a solution, and may go up or down. The 'Best Integer' values should behave monotonically as better integer-feasible solutions are found.

Comment: Okay perfect thank you, this makes sense now, just out of curiosity where were you able to find this information please? do you have any reference you would like to share please. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no obvious reference for this - I have been using CPLEX for over 20 years (I worked for ILOG as an optim consultant 1994-2003) so for me it is now completely obvious, and I don't remember where I learned it. Probably from an internal training course given by the R&D team.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have a look at

[image]

in

https://fr.slideshare.net/mobile/IBMOptimization/2013-11-informsminingthenodelog

Answer (score 2):

The user manual includes a detailed explanation of this log in section

CPLEX->User's Manual for CPLEX->Discrete Optimization->Solving Mixed Integer Programming Problems (MIP)->Progress Reports: interpreting the node log

(see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/para/52_node_log.html)